# Did any jurisdiction ever restrict franchise purely by IQ?

Tags: voter-registration

As we all know, 100% universal franchise is fiction - in every country, no matter how democratic, SOME people are excluded from franchise (felons, under-18-year-olds,  foreign nationals, etc...).

Was there ever a political<sup>[1]</sup> jurisdiction that restricted franchise very explicitly by intelligence threshold<sup>[2]</sup><sup>[3]</sup> (e.g., you can vote at 13, if you're smart enough, but you can't vote at 30 if you're not smart enough to be trusted to vote).

<sub>[1] - I am clearly excluding cases where the electorate themselves are naturally IQ clustered, such as academia elections. Just general, at-large governance elections are in scope.</sub>

<sub>[2] - Intelligence as measured reasonably directly - e.g. while someone may (correctly or not) claim that a poll tax is correlated to a degree with intelligence, the example is out of scope for the question, unless the organizers explicitly proved that their proxy test both highly correlates with intelligence, AND upfront-explained it this way. FWIW, usually poll taxes are explain in ways unrelated to intelligece</sub>

<sub>[3] - Issues such as whether IQ or some other measure to verify intelligence work or not; or if they are "fair" or not, is outside the scope.</sub>

Comment: Does allowing to vote depending on whether you have graduated a university count?

Comment: @Anixx - as per #2, only if it's explicitly explained up-front as a proxy for intelligence by people passing such a rule, and not as some other reason (e.g. if the reason is "this elected post mostly only affects the university system", that doesn't count)

Comment: Would literacy tests that really had the intention of excluding African Americans in the US south count?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - I believe they still wouldn't allow people who pass a literacy test BUT were underage to vote, so they won't count, sorry.

Comment: Was there ever even a jurisdiction that didn't have an age restriction? I might believe that some jurisdictions limited only by age and an intelligence test, but it seems unlikely that they didn't limit by age (intelligence tests, like IQ tests, can be taken be relatively young children).

Comment: @Avi - That's the point. If you're claiming that you're excluding by age because younger people can't make as good of a choice as they lack brains/knowledge/wisdom, then a solution based on IQ test and not age is more accurate.

Comment: That's not true if you're arguing for knowledge. IQ tests don't test for knowledge, they test for intelligence.

Comment: @user4012 “I believe they still wouldn't allow people who pass a literacy test BUT were underage to vote, so they won't count, sorry.” Would it be okay with you if I edited the question to say that it has to be the only method of restricting voting?

Answer (score 3):

Always hard to prove a negative, but I'm reasonably sure the answer is no.

The idea of standardised testing is a relatively recent idea in the West. IQ tests were only developed at the start of the 20th century. So there won't be any examples from pre-modern times in western democracies.

In modern times there have been cases of the use of "literacy tests" but these were primarily about excluding particular races, not people with lower intelligence. Age restrictions also applied.  Indeed it is hard to find a jurisdiction in which there isn't an age limit of some type.

The Chinese system of government was based on a system of testing, but this was not a test to allow you to vote, but a test that gave you access to the ranks of the civil service.

There have been a few "university constituencies".  These represent graduates of the university and not a geographical area. If you look at the University of Dublin constituency it represents graduates of the university in the senate, and you need to graduate to vote in this constituency.  The ability to graduate is related to intelligence, but obviously, there are other factors.

I conclude that no country or constituency has used IQ tests or a similar measure of intelligence as the only or principle restriction to voting.